# Where to store .py files when i need to execute them in mininet

Tags: python, mininet, sdn

I'm new to mininet and python. I have set up ubuntu on virtual box and i'm running mininet on it. I've set up putty and xming server as well. I am successfully able to ssh into mininet using putty. I'm able to run commands and create custom topologies (linear, tree etc) using these commands like:

```
sudo mn --topo minimal
```

Now i need to run a python script through mininet to create the topologies. I've seen a few video tutorials. I'm unsure of where to store the .py file. The command to run the script on mininet is

```
sudo python filename.py
```

Where should this file be stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the script only creates a topology (as in http://mininet.org/walkthrough/#custom-topologies ) you provide its path to the command line:
sudo mn --custome /path/to/file --topo

Another way is to have the script create mininet and the topology via Python API, so instead of running 'mn' you actually run the script, for example https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/examples/simpleperf.py